# Multiple project visual studio solution won't debug one project dll

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have been working with multiple projects (3-5, 1 exe, rest dll) in a solution and have not had any problems till now. Now one of my projects (dll) won't debug in the solution. The exe and two dlls are c# and the rest are vb. The vb dlls are the ones that won't work now. We have just changed source control and I dropped and added the projects back together and that is the biggest difference. Since then I am receiving "the breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document", error. It is not showing in the debug->windows->modules and so far I have added it and dropped it, reset references to all solutions, rebooted and researched all over the internet. Also, I am working with Visual Studio 15.

Comment: the main problem is if one dll is referenced by another (dll or exe) and they are built on different target platform. It has nothing to do with the language (either VB or C#).

Comment: I have run all five of these at the same time before.

Comment: well, they can run independently, but when you try to reference them, it will fail

Comment: I meant that I have debugged through all five of them before.

Comment: I understand. What platform do they target?

Comment: .net framework 4 for c# and .net framework 2 for vb

Comment: and do you try to use some methods from one inside another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally got this to work, thanks to one of my co-workers. I  was referencing the dll from the bin folder in my exe. We deleted the reference and created a new reference linking it directly to the debug folder of the dll. I could then step into the dll.

Answer (score 2):

The dlls have not been loaded to the process which you are trying to debug, under project properties check if optimize code is checked-in this will cause VS to see assembly as "not my code", it will not load symbols for it.
[image]

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see a check box for optimize code. When I enter properties there is a list on the side that starts application, compile, debug,etc... I have been through all the settings and could not find anything like that.

Comment: I have added the image, go to properties on your main/startup project level you will be able to find

Comment: The application is a dll. I do not seem to have many of the options that you have.

Comment: I actually found the  properties like you are showing but only for my C# components not the VB